scroll outer div before inner div
I would like to scroll an outer div before i scroll an inner div.
In the setup below, when I touch & scroll .content, the .inner div scrolls first, and afterwards the .outer div.
I would like to have the .outer div scroll first and then the .inner div.
Is there some option to re-order elements in the scroll-chain?


* {
    overflow:scroll;
    position:relative;
}
.outer {
    height: 20vh;
    background-color: green;
    width:300px;
}

.inner {
    height: 50vh;
    background-color: red;
    width:250px;
}

.content {
    height: 70vh;
    background-color: blue;
    width:200px;  
}
<div class="outer">shall 1st, scrolls 2nd
    <div class="inner">shall 2nd, scrolls 1st
        <div class="content">scroll in here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




does this answer your question?
